# How to populate the nested objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

here's the booking schema

```
const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  routeId:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Route",
    required: true,
  }
})
```

In this table the routeId(route schema) contains the Bus table(referenced).

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Location',
    required: true
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  Bus:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"Bus",
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true,
});
```

and then finally the bus model

```
const busSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    busNumber: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    seats: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Now I want to show only bus number and not whole bus data. this is the response I am getting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1qyZ.png

this is the query that I applied.

```
router.get("/bus/myBooking/one/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  const myBooking = await Booking.findById({ _id })
    .populate({path: 'routeId', populate: 'Bus'})
    .select(["-_id","-userId","-createdAt","-updatedAt","-__v","-passengers._id","-departureDetails._id","-arrivalDetails._id"]);
  try {
    return !myBooking
      ? res.status(404).send("No booking found")
      : res.status(200).send(myBooking);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method works on some versions of mongoose, So you can try this:

```
 await Booking.findById({ _id })
  .populate({ 
   path: 'routeId',
      populate: {
         path: 'Bus',
         model: Bus,
         select:"-_id busNumber"
   } 
 })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13359244/milad-khajavi . thank you for the answer milad that works but now the problem is that is populating all the data inside of the routeId like _id, createdAt, updatedAt. how to exclude them as well

Comment: you can select wichever you need .. like subset populate (Bus)

for example:

`populate({ path: 'routeId', select: "Bus location duration" , populate: {path: 'Bus', model: Bus, select:"-_id busNumber"}})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13359244/milad-khajavi . it is returning routeId to null