How do I use populate method if I have a separate mapping collection?
I have below collections

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  // other item properties
});

const storeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  // other store properties
});

const storeItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  store: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store' },
  item: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' },
  // other storeItem properties
});

I am trying to fetch stores with items like below, but getting an error Cannot populate path "items" because it is not in your schema. Set the "strictPopulate" option to false to override
return this.storeModel.find({},{_id:1}).populate('items')


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72392187/how-to-populate-the-nested-objects-in-mongoose

Is storeModel the model for storeSchema or storeItemSchema? From what I can see, if you were to create a model named storeItemModel from the storeItemSchema then a simple await storeItemModel.find({},{_id:1}).populate('item') would work. Note your field name is item and not items.


Cannot populate path "items" because it is not in your schema. Set the "strictPopulate" option to false to override

Please review the statement: The path given in populate is 'items', as per the schema - storeItemSchema, it must be 'item'.
return this.storeModel.find({},{_id:1}).populate('items')

